# Variable decleration in a 'try except' block of a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, recursion, scope

was trying to declare variable t in the first iteration of a recursion

```
class c:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.n=a
```

```
def a():
    t=c(5)
    def b():
        print(t.n)
    b()
```

does print t

```
def d():
    try:
        t
        print(t.n)
    except:
        t=c(5)
        d()
```

doenst print t

I don't understand the difference and why in the first function does work and the second doesn't

Comment: ```t``` is local to the specific call of ```d()``` and hence always unbound when ```d()``` is called.

Comment: You could declare *global t* immediately before *try*. That will solve this particular problem but it's intriguing trying to understand what your objective is. globals used unnecessarily are generally frowned upon

Comment: i had hw to do some recursion problem and i wanted to do it without define another func inside the main func

Comment: i still dont undesrstand why
t is local to a() and that why b will print t
but why isnt t local to the outer d (just like a) 
and the inner d will behave like b

Answer (score 2):

it won't print `t` because `t` is a local variable to each function call and is not recognized in the context of the other calls to `d`. if you want to use it you either have to make it global or pass it as an argument

```py
def d(t=None):
    try:
        print(t.n)
    except:
        t=c(5)
        d(t=t)
d()
```

## More explanation

(There is a great [video](https://youtu.be/jXugs4B3lwU) about this by mCoding i recommend you watch, and the content of the channel is pretty good)

### Why is it local in `d` but not `b` ?

What happens is: at compile time python will look at your function and  see is `t` defined anywhere in your function? if yes (the case of `d` , even if the variable is assigned after it's usage), it will take the value from that scope, if not it will try finding it in the next scope and so on. if it doesn't find it, it will assume it's a global.

for example:

```py
variable = 1
def method_1():
    print(variable)
    variable = 2
method_1()
```

will throw an error even tho variable is defined in the global scope because the compiler found that we are assigning variable inside the function

on the other hand:

```py
variable = 1
def method_2()
    print(variable)

method_2()
```

will work because the compiler considers variable global

Comment: i still dont undesrstand why
t is local to a() and that why b will print t
but why isnt t local to the outer d (just like a) 
and the inner d will behave like b

Comment: @idonthavename i added more to the answer does it explain it better now ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second code, when an exception occurs because `t` is not defined it moves to the except block, and what does the except block do?
It creates a variable called `t` but it is a local variable to that call of the function on the stack and then calls the function again which does the same thing because when you call the function again a new memory is allocated to that function call on the stack and `t` is not defined in that function call. Hence, it throws an exception and does the same thing again.

[image]

As you can see in the picture an Infinite number of function calls is made until a stack overflow error happens which leads to the termination of your running program because it never breaks out of the try-except block because each time a function call is made `t` is defined locally to the function call and make another call which doesn't have `t` defined in it's scope.

Comment: i still dont undesrstand why
t is local to a() and that why b will print t
but why isnt t local to the outer d (just like a) 
and the inner d will behave like b

Comment: In the first example `t` is defined in the outer function `a()` so the inner function `b()` has `t` also defined because it is in its scope of definition.
But in the second example as illustrated in the answer the calls of the function on the stack don't have the same scope of definition so the first call has its own defined `t` and the second call doesn't have `t` defined in its scope.

Comment: why they dont have the same scope
why a call b same scope but d call d isnt?

Comment: because `b` is defined inside `a` which makes it able to see definitions made in the scope of `a` because `b` is literally defined inside `a` not outside `a` if you try to define it outside it will not be able to see the local definition scope of `a`.

When `d` calls `d` that doesn't mean they have the same scope of definition each call to `d` will have it's own local scope.

Comment: generally speaking, each function call has its own local scope but because `b` was defined inside of `a` it has it's own local scope, and the local scope of `a` is available to `b` because it was defined inside of `a`.